# How to allow many IP address to connect MemCache Server

Tags: java, caching, memcached, spymemcached

I want to allow many IP address to connect my memcache server. 
In memcache.conf,I tried with
 `-l ip,ip2` and some other appraches. but they didn't work. Any Idea how to connect ?
 `-l 0.0.0.0` works for any IP. But I want to limit for given IP addresses.

Comment: Is this a programming question (in which case show us your code) or is this "how do I configure software" question which would be better sent to a forum supporting this product?

Comment: @PeterLawrey. If you don't know, you may avoid answering. Those who know, let them support.